# What is the new asynch feature introduced in servlet 3.1?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-3.0

I start reading about jee 7 and one thing i read is:

"Servlet technology has allowed only traditional (blocking) input/output during request processing since its inception. In the Servlet 3.1 release, the new Non-Blocking I/O API makes it possible for servlets to read or write without any blocking"

How true is this statement since Servlet 3.0 introduced the AsyncContext and the asynch servlet?

"This means that other tasks can be performed at the same time as a read or write is occurring, without any wait. This in turn means that now you can more easily accomplish Ajax and partial-page refreshes without making separate calls to the servlet for each update"

So what is the new feature introduced in servlet 3.1 compared to 3.0 specs for asynch servlets ?

Thanks

Comment: I read that article before ...still not clear if in the servlet 3.0 why it was not possible to do that.In servlet 3.0 i could have started a new thread from a custom thread pool and do the job by reading from input stream

Comment: Surely it uses an internal Thread pool in 3.1 to handle the case but it exempts you to manage it or even guessing its existence. Using 3.0, you would have to manage it yourself ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excerpt of this [description](http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/non_blocking_i_o_using):

> Servlet 3.0 allowed asynchronous request processing but only
>   traditional I/O was permitted. This can restrict scalability of your
>   applications.
>
> This is resolved in Servet 3.1 (JSR 340, to be released as part Java
>   EE 7) by adding event listeners - ReadListener and WriteListener
>   interfaces. These are then registered using
>   ServletInputStream.setReadListener and
>   ServletOutputStream.setWriteListener. The listeners have callback
>   methods that are invoked when the content is available to be read or
>   can be written without blocking.

Thus, to sum up, Servlet 3.1 extends the possible use cases dealing with Non-blocking I/O.

Comment: Exactly that part i want to understand...so in 3.1 there was new API introduced that allows to read,write from a stream in a non blocking manner ? maybe i need then to understand how non blocking io is working.Thanks.

Comment: Exactly, more usages can fit NIO now with 3.1